# add favicon - <doctype! html> not <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: html, favicon

I need to add favicon to my website but it is `<doctype! html>` and when I add commands as this nothing happens

```
<link rel="icon" href="/static//ico/favicon.png">
```

when  `<doctype! html>`  to `<!DOCTYPE html>` , some of sizes change and Ui details change.

I use python3 and flask.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: `<doctype! html>` is not a thing; it’s an error. You need to keep `<!DOCTYPE html>`, which is the correct version, and fix your layout so that it works again outside of [quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, but please add more code so I can help you

**Update**

I looked at your code and I think that you need to change the `height` in `msg-wrapper-body` class from `100%` to `100vh` and it will fix your problem.

Comment: Hi. [Here](https://github.com/Revisto/MadadChat) is my code on github.

Comment: can you say what is your problem with more detail

Comment: yes, [Here](https://img.techpowerup.org/200903/screenshot-from-2020-09-03-20-10-12.png) is my problem with the WebPage. The size of ChatBar (input area) at the bottom becomes more than the usual

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 main issues with your code:

1. `<DOCTYPE! HTML>` renders in quirks mode causing some things to not work, change it to `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` and fix the layouts.
2. You have a `//` in your file path that shouldn't be there, change that to `/`.